# How to i update an iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3.5 offline

Tags: iphone, software-update, ios

i was able to update my iPhone 4S and iPad via the option on the settings menu however i iPhone 4 which i use as my music player doesn't have that option, my computer with itunes doesn't connect to the internet so i can't download it via itunes

i am wondering if there is an offline installer i can download that itune can detect to use, that way i can download it on a separate computer then transfer it to my main computer

Comment: This is not possible. Apple requires online verification of iOS during install. Sadly this means you will need an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

There exists [direct download links](http://osxdaily.com/2013/09/26/ios-7-0-2-update-available-download/) for the restore images that you can download from one computer and use for the restore on your own computer, however you will still need an internet connection for the final part of the installation (iTunes needs to verify with Apple servers).

Once you have the .ipsw file on your computer, hold down <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> (or control if on a PC) while clicking 'Update' in iTunes, and select the .ipsw file for your iPhone.

Comment: The verification isn't actually the final part. That comes right after unpacking and verifying package if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do an offline upgrade iOS to iOS 7.1, follow the steps in this guide

http://echo.com.ng/2013/howto-apple-ios-7-offline-manual-upgrade

Comment: Please explain the steps, because the link might die.